# How to extract multiple short video clips from a long video using python?

Tags: python, moviepy, data-preprocessing

How to extract multiple smaller video clips from a long video using some python package, I need it as part of my video preprocessing for my project.
ffmpeg is a method but its too complex.
Any other method would be really helpful.

I tried using moviepy, but the documentation is not that clear, so I could only extract one video at a time and not multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Moviepy package, we can extract multiple smaller clips from a large video.

```
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip

def extract_clips(video_file, clip_duration, clip_start_times):
    clip_list = []
    with VideoFileClip(video_file) as video:
        for start_time in clip_start_times:
            clip = video.subclip(start_time, start_time + clip_duration)
            clip_list.append(clip)
    return clip_list

video_file = "path/to/your/video.mp4"
clip_duration = 5  # duration of each clip in seconds
clip_start_times = [0, 10, 20]  # start times of each clip in seconds

clips = extract_clips(video_file, clip_duration, clip_start_times)

# save the clips to disk
for i, clip in enumerate(clips):
    clip.write_videofile("clip_{}.mp4".format(i))
```

The function takes in parameters, the video file, the total play time of the clip and the start times of wherever you want it to cut at.

You can use the write_videofile() to save these clips into the desired location in your system.

I hope this gives some more clarity on how to perform this operation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank You for your suggestions. please tell if the current version needs any changes.